# Help with a logic problem (given this, prove this).

Tags: logic

Here is the problem:

[image: x]

Here is my progress.

We have:

i. $p \implies q$

ii. $r \vee s$

iii. $r \implies t$

iv. $\neg q$

v. $s \implies p$

Start with $r \vee s$. Suppose $r$. Since $r \implies t$, $t$ must be true.

Now suppose $s$. Since $s \implies p$, $p$ must be true. Then since $p \implies q$, $q$ must be true. But $q$ is false, since $\neg q$. So our original assumption $s$ is false.

Since $r$, then $t$.

Is this enough? Don't both $r$ and $s$ have to be true? I'm thinking this because I was taught that to prove $(a \vee b) \implies c$, you must prove that $a \implies c$ *and* $b \implies c$, since that is logically equivalent - that is,

$(a \vee b) \implies c \equiv (a \implies c) \wedge (b \implies c)$.

Comment: pleas don't post pictures of text but  replace the picture by text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this enough?

Yes.   It is a good proof.

> Don't both $r$ and $s$ have to be true?

No; just *at least one* needs to be true and *that* one needs to imply the required conclusion $(t)$.

When we don't know which from the two is true, we will need both to imply the same consequent, but when we *do know which is true*, we only need that one to do so.   See below.

> I'm thinking this because I was taught that to prove
> $(a\vee b)\to c$, you must prove that $a\to c$ and $b\to c$, since that is logically equivalent - that is.  $(a\vee b)\to c \equiv (a\to c)\wedge (b\to c)$

Yes, indeed, you may infer $c$ from $a\vee b, a\to c,$ and $b\to c$.  (This is the rule of "disjunction elimination" in *natural deduction* proof systems)

But have you not *also* been taught that $b\to c$ may be infered from $\neg b$, whatever $c$ may be?   (Conditionals are true whenever their antecedants are false. )

So you may *also* infer $c$ from $a\vee b, a\to c,$ and $\neg b$.

---

> Given premises: i. $p\to q$, ii. $r\vee s$, iii. $r\to t$, iv. $¬q$, v. $s\to p$
>
> Infer $\neg s$ from premises v., i., and iv. ($s\to p, p\to q, \neg q$), since assuming $s$ with those derives a contradiction.
>
> Infer $s\to t$ from $\neg s$, since assuming $s$ derives a contradiction via which anything may be derived.   (Notice how we might combine this with the previous step.)
>
> Infer $t$ from $s\to t$ and premises ii. and iii. ($r\vee s, r\to t$).
>
> Thereby infering $t$ from the five premises.
>
> $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

It's ok but it's kind of all upside down.

$p\Rightarrow q$ can be rewritten $\neg q\Rightarrow \neg p$,

$s\Rightarrow p$ can be rewritten $\neg p\Rightarrow \neg s$,

$s\vee t$ can be rewritten $\neg s\Rightarrow t$.

By transitivity you have $\neg q\Rightarrow t$.

Comment: $s\vee t$ is not among the premises.  However, we do have $r\vee s$, and $r{\implies }t$, so that's just one more step.

Comment: My bad. That's right.